# Desktop organizer program

Tags: windows, file-management

If I keep 15 image files on my desktop, could there be a program that pops up "Do you wish to create a folder of these files?" or similar so that the desktop automatically keeps organized and not becomes full?

Or a similar tool to keep a folder automatically organized by automatically grouping similar files together.

I use Windows 10.

Comment: It is never a good idea to place actual items, rather than shortcuts, on the desktop as it uses a lot of system resources and in the workplace your desktop is often backed up to a server on shutdown then restored on startup so things get very slow.

Comment: @SteveBarnes That's good to know, thank you. I suppose I can write a script that traverses the file system and finds all image files etc but I think a program like Picasa already does that for images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [DropIt](http://www.dropitproject.com/)

Similar to Hygeia in Sonamor's answer, DropIt is a tool that helps manage your files.

It comes with a few template profiles, but you can create your own. Profiles contain rules for different kinds of filters. It can be set to either run on command or automatically monitor a folder. For example, the situation you describe can be addressed with the following rule:

[image]

Other notable features:

- Runs on Windows
- Is free and open source
- Has a portable version

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Hygeia](http://www.purllow.com/) [Tip: Means health in Greek] and create some custom rules that will run on interval or whenever you want.

I did the same for my Downloads folder, were every night at 00:00, it will automatically move files to different folders based on filetype and filename.

It's easy to use and I really love it.

[image]

[image]